# React swipe navigation

Tags: reactjs, swipe

[swipeable navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pIot.jpg)

Whats the best approach to make link area swipeable left and right?
Ive failed to find ready to use component that allows to do that.
Ive tried to use React Touch SyntheticEvent and transform translateX to navigation bar, but failed with calculations. So question is what are the ways to achieve that and is there any react components that can help me to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you need to have a look at [there](https://github.com/zy410419243/react-mobile-component/blob/master/src/component/Swiper/Swiper.js).
- Although it only supports element swipeable up and down, you can refer to the code of how the author implements element swipeable with translate3d.
- The main idea of swiper is to calculate the position of the element, and when to start translation. You can record **scrollHeight/scrollWidth** and **offsetHeight/offsetWidth** when you start move event, and compare the value of them when the event is end. Then you know where is the element, and you can control the transform of the element as you want.
- So far as I know, maybe [Iscroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) is a good solution for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)